# Funcion en C# que retorne un arreglo de texto de dos posiciones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo el siguiente inciso de un ejercicio en C#:

Una función que retorne un arreglo de texto de dos posiciones, en la primera posición tendrá el nombre del equipo ganador del torneo y en la segunda posición, los puntos que obtuvo. Luego limpiar ambos arreglos.

ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO ESCRITO PERO NO ESTOY SEGURO SI ESTARÁ BIEN, ME GUSTARÍA QUE LO REVISEN Y ME AYUDEN SI HAY QUE HACERLE CAMBIOS.

Saludos.

```
 public string[] EquipoGanador()
    {

        string[] EquipoGanador = { };
        int puntosG = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            EquipoGanador[0] = Ganador;
            EquipoGanador[1] = puntosG.ToString();
        }

        return EquipoGanador;
    }
```

Comment: eso compila?, Ganador parece un objeto, no un string.. o tiene un metodo automatico toString? igual no entiendo el for ni nada de eso que hace este codigo...

Answer (score 2):

No retornaria un array, recomendaria hagas uson de clases para definir los datos, algo como ser:

```
 public class Juego {
    public string Ganador {get;set;}
    public string Puntos {get;set;}
 }
```

entonces usas

```
   public List<Juego> EquipoGanador()
    {
       List<Juego> juegos = new List<Juego>();

       for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
       {
           Juego juego = new Juego();
           juego.Ganador = Ganador;
           juego.Puntos = puntosG.ToString();

           juegos.Add(juego);
        }

        return juegos;
    }
```

asi queda mucho mejor que usas array, al usar `List<>` puedes ir agregando items dinamicamente mientras iteras